# How to execute a nested loop with dataframes for regression analysis

Tags: python, pandas, regression

How can I execute a nested loop that goes through two data frames to acquire every combination of the columns within the nested loop. This is for acquiring the various r^2 values across the various combinations utilizing OLS Regression

For example:
DF1 consists of:

```
    50      51      52      53
0   73.44   63.44   53.46   44.49
1   395.01  369.01  343.01  317.49
2   339.75  312.76  286.8   262.8
```

DF2 consists of:

```
    50      51      52      53
0   153.81  173.81  193.83  214.86
1   19.98   23.98   27.98   32.46
2   3.06    5.07    8.11    13.11
```

How can I get every single combination of both data frame columns and execute the

Here is my code below:

```
g=50
h=53
for g in range(50, 53):

    q =[ round(elem, 2) for elem in DF1[g].iloc[0:].tolist() ]

    for h in range(50, 53):

        z =[ round(elem, 2) for elem in DF2[h].iloc[0:].tolist() ]
        x = np.row_stack((q,z))
        x = np.array(x).T
        x = sm.add_constant(x)
        results = sm.OLS(endog=y, exog=x).fit()
        my_list.append(results.rsquared)
        h += 1
    g+=1
```

For some reason I am not getting all the combinations of the columns? Any Suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by `getting all combinations of columns` ?

Comment: so like column 50 of df1 then column 50 of df1, next column 50 of df1 and column 51 of df2, and so on until I get every combination. As the loop is processing, it is turning the columns into a list and going regressional analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `range(50, 54)` or use `iteritems`. This should show 4x4=16 outputs in total.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({50: [73.44, 395.01, 339.75],
                    51: [63.44, 369.01, 312.76],
                    52: [53.46, 343.01, 286.8],
                    53: [44.49, 317.49, 262.8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({50: [153.81, 19.98, 3.06],
                    51: [173.81, 27.98, 5.07],
                    52: [193.83, 27.98, 8.11],
                    53: [214.86, 32.46, 13.11]})

for _, g in df1.iteritems():
    for _, h in df2.iteritems():
        print(np.row_stack((g, h)))
# [[  73.44  395.01  339.75]
#  [ 153.81   19.98    3.06]]
# ...
# [[  44.49  317.49  262.8 ]
#  [ 214.86   32.46   13.11]]
```